# Failed to authenticate with SailsJS and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sails.js

Hello I'm a newbie in sails and postgresql so I have a folder contains a fully working sails-apps from my friend and a file postgreDB.backup. and when I tried to `sails lift` it on cmd its error says `A hook <'orm'> failed to load!` and `error : failed to authenticate the password for user ? postgres ? at Connection.parseE ...` so what should I do exactly to make it working when I get this sails-apps folder and a postgredatabase ? thanks a bunch.

Comment: Check config/connections.js (or datastores.js if you're using version 1) as this is where the database config is stored. It seems that you have configured a username and password for the database in Sails but your database is using a different username and password.

Comment: yes.. it seems that i only have to insert the Sails password on config/connections.js. and it worked wonderfully. thank you so much